# php - split string by spaces and quotes without spaces into array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Lets say I've a following strings

```
$string1 = 'hello world my name is'
```

and

```
$string2 = '"hello world" my name is'
```

using this with string1:

```
preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/', $string1, $matches);
```

I get an array:

```
echo $matches[0][0]//hello
echo $matches[0][1] //world
```

using the same but with string2:

```
preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/', $string2, $matches);
```

I get an array:

```
echo $matches[0][0] //"hello world"
echo $matches[0][1] //my
```

but if my string is:

```
 " hello world " my name is 
//^^          ^^(notice the spaces at beginning and end ),
```

I would get:

```
echo $matches[0][0] //" hello world "
```

when I really want to get

```
"hello world"
```

how to modify the first argument in `preg_match_all`? any other simple solution? thanks

Comment: Why can't use preg_match_all('/hello world/', $string1, $matches);if you want only 'hello world'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$string = '" hello world " my name is';
$string = preg_replace('/"\s*(.*?)\s*"/', '"$1"', $string);
echo ($string);
echo "<br />";
// OUTPUt : "hello world" my name is

preg_match_all('/"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"|\S+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
// OUTPUt : Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => "hello world" [1] => my [2] => name [3] => is ) )

echo implode(' ', $matches[0]);
// OUTPUt : "hello world" my name is
```